# Do I need to .SaveChanges() in order get an ID for a foreign key?

Tags: entity-framework-4

In the following code, I'm saving a new person and then grabbing the person's id to use as a FK in the associated address record. PKs are defined as identify columns in the db. My question, do I need to call dc.SaveChanges(); after adding the person to the object set? Is there any way to avoid a trip to the db to get the ID and then pass it to the address as a FK? Can I roll both savechanges() into one operation?

```
            PlaygroundEntities dc = new PlaygroundEntities();

            Person person = new Person
                                {
                                    FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
                                    LastName = txtLastName.Text
                                };

            dc.People.AddObject(person);
            dc.SaveChanges();

            Address address = new Address
                                  {
                                      PeopleId = person.Id,
                                      Address1 = txtAddress.Text,
                                      City = txtCity.Text,
                                      State = txtState.Text,
                                      ZipCode = txtZipCode.Text
                                  };

            dc.Addresses.AddObject(address);
            dc.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve person.Id without query as long as person.Id is auto-generating key.
However, if the purpose of getting person.Id is just to create address, you don't need to address person.Id, you just add person with address as follow :

```
    Person person = new Person 
                    { 
                       FirstName = txtFirstName.Text, 
                       LastName = txtastName.Text, 
                       Address = new Address
                                 { 
                                    Address1=txtAddress.Text, 
                                    City=txtCity.Text, 
                                    State=txtState.Text, 
                                    ZipCode=txtZipCode.Text 
                                 }
                     }

dc.People.AddObject(person);
dc.SaveChanges();
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person person = new Person
    {
                                FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
                                LastName = txtLastName.Text
                            };


        Address address = new Address
                              {
                                  People = person,
                                  Address1 = txtAddress.Text,
                                  City = txtCity.Text,
                                  State = txtState.Text,
                                  ZipCode = txtZipCode.Text
                              };

        dc.Addresses.AddObject(address);
        dc.SaveChanges();
```

Per your example, instead of saving and adding id, add object reference then save once.